# Matlab: vertical lines at x-values specified by vector

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a vector of x-values at which I would like to add vertical lines to a graph, say a row vector: `vec = [1 2 3 4 5]`

I know that you can add single vertical lines like this:

`plot([1 1],[0 1])`

(gives a vertical line at x=1 from y=0 to y=1).

But when I try something like

`vec = [1 2 3 4 5];
lowLine = [0 0 0 0 0];
highLine = [1 1 1 1 1];
plot([vec vec],[lowLine highLine])`

It does not give the required result, instead it gives a z-shape. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try `plot([vec;vec],[lowLine;highLine])`. MATLAB's plot sees each column of input matrices as different plots, not the rows

Comment: @BillBokeey thanks, works!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, feel free to accept it so that the others know it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot several lines in a single plot, you need to use the fact that MATLAB's `plot` function handles matrices as inputs, and that it sees each column of the inputs as different plots :

> If X and Y are both matrices, then they must have equal size. The plot
>   function plots columns of Y versus columns of X.

Thus, in order to get the expected result, you need to write :

```
vec = [1 2 3 4 5];
lowLine = [0 0 0 0 0];
highLine = [1 1 1 1 1];
plot([vec;vec],[lowLine;highLine])
```

**Result :**

[image]